# HTTP error 405 when forwarding servlet POST request

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, servlets

**I am a Java Newbie so please be patient.** I made this program which matches my password and username from database. If I type the correct password then this pops up

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL).


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

But when I type the wrong password, expected output comes up (i.e. navigation to www.google.com). I am not able to find the error.
My code is:

```
package httpserv1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Httpserv extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init() throws ServletException {    
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String name = request.getParameter("name1");
        String password = request.getParameter("password1");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String userName = "sa";
            String password2 = "iyoginet$123";
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.36.15:8307;databaseName=master";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password2);
            Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = ((java.sql.Statement) stmt)
                    .executeQuery("SELECT PASSWORD FROM LOGON WHERE NAME='" + name + "'");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String pass = rs.getString(1);

                if (password.equalsIgnoreCase(pass)) {
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Serv");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.co.in");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Good Bye ! !");
    }
}
```

According to my code, if I enter the wrong password it should get forwarded to another servlet(i.e. serv).

Comment: Beside your actual question you should never store you password clear in you DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are forwarding the exactly same request (which is a POST) to another `Servlet ("Serv")`. I assume that your second `Servlet ("Serv")` cannot handle POST requests (because it does not have a doPost-Method). You should probably use:

```
response.sendRedirect("/Serv");
```

replace `"/Serv"` with the path to your `servlet`.

Comment: silly mistake, i realized i was using doget method in second servlet i.e. serv. It works fine now.